# CodeIgniter - where to put functions / classes?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Am having problems understanding where classes should be kept in CI. I am building an application that describes / markets mobile phones.

I would like for all of my functions (i.e. getphone, getdetails etc.) to reside in one class called Mobile - I understand that this file should be called Mobile.php and reside in the controllers folder.

Can I then have multiple functions inside Mobile.php? E.g.

```
public function getphone() {
   xxx
   xx
   xx
}

public function getdetails() {
   xxx
   xx
   xx
}
```

Or do I need to put each function in its own class?

I'd really appreciate looking at some sample code that works. I've been going through the documentation and google for a few hours, and tried all sorts of variations in the URL to find a test class, but without much luck! I've even messed around with the routes and .htaccess...

All I am trying to achieve is the following:

http:///model/HTC-Desire/ to be re-routed to a function that accepts HTC-Desire as  a parameter (as I need it for a DB lookup). The default controller works fine, but can't get anything to work thereafter.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Actually it works like this:

Controllers and Models go to their perspective folders as you know it

If you want to create functions that are not methods of an object, you must create a helper file. More info here :
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Now if you want to create your own datatypes (classes that don't extend Models and Controllers), you add them to the library folder. So if let's say you want to create a class "Car" you create this file:

```
class Car{

   function __construct(){}
}
```

and save it in the libraries folder as car.php

To create an instance of the Car class you must do the following:

```
$this->load->library('car');
$my_car = new Car();
```

More information on libraries here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many functions in a controller class as you'd like. They are accessible via the url `/class/function`.

You can catch parameters in the class functions, though it's not advisable.

```
class Mobile extends CI_Controller{

    public function getPhone($phoneModel=''){
        echo $phoneModel;
        //echo $this->input->post('phoneModel');
    }
}
```

*http://site.com/mobile/getPhone/HTC-Rad* theoretically would echo out "HTC-Rad". **HOWEVER**, special characters are not welcome in URL's in CI by default, so in this example you may be met with a 'Disallowed URI characters" error instead. You'd be better off passing the phone model (or any other parameters) via `$_POST` to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can exist both as `Controllers` and `Models`, as CodeIgniter implements the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). I recommend reading more about that to understand how your classes/functions/etc. can best be organized.

Off the top of my head, [Pyro CMS](http://www.pyrocms.com/) is an application built with CodeIgniter and the source code is freely available. I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best you handle it from one perspective, that is; create a utility class with all your functions in it.
The answer to the question of where to put/place the class file is the "libraries" folder.
This is clearly stated in the documentation. **Place your class in the libraries folder**.

> When we use the term “Libraries” we are normally referring to the
>   classes that are located in the libraries directory and described in
>   the Class Reference of this user guide.

You can read more on creating and using libraries [Creating Libraries — CodeIgniter 3.1.10 documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

After placing the newly created class in the libraries folder, to use just simply load the library within your controller as shown below:

```
$this->load->library('yourphpclassname');
```

If you wish to receive several arguments within you constructor you have to modify it to receive an argument which would be an array and you loading/initialization would then be slightly different as shown below:

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');

$this->load->library('yourphpclassname', $params);
```

Then, to access any of the functions within the class simply do that as shown below:

```
$this->yourphpclassname->some_method();
```

I hope this answers your question if you have further question do leave a comment and I would do well to respond to them.